# Saving Python Complex Data Types to Amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

Can Python class data be saved to S3 without marshalling? I am trying to cut down of I/O operations until necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 stores plain data files. Even if there's a library that makes it look like objects are being saved, it's going to do marshalling in the background. Might as well just [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) your objects by yourself.